# How do I show that $2a$ is the diameter of $A=(-a,a)$?

Tags: real-analysis

proof. Suppose that $A = (-a,a) = (-a,0]\cup [0,a)$ and let $x \in [0,a)$ and $y\in (-a,0]$ . Then $x + \epsilon = a = \sup A$ for some $\epsilon > 0$ and $y-\beta = -a = \inf A$ for some $\beta >0$. So,

$2a=a-(-a)=x+\epsilon -(y-\beta)=|x-y| + (\epsilon + \beta)$. Then

$2a \ge |x-y|$.

Would I have to show that $2a$ is the supremum of $|x-y|$ by also showing the cases when $x,y \in (-a,0]$ , and $x,y \in [0,a)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can prove that the diameter is $\le 2a$ like this. Take any $x,y \in (-a,a)$. Now consider two cases.

- If $x \le y$ then $-a < x \le y < a$ and so $|x-y|=y-x<a-(-a)=2a$.
- If $y \le x$ then $-a < y \le x < a$ and so $|x-y|=x-y<a-(-a)=2a$.

Next you can prove that the diameter is $\ge 2a$ like this. For any $\epsilon \in (0,a)$ we have $-a < -a+\frac{\epsilon}{2} < a - \frac{\epsilon}{2} < a$ and so the diameter is $\ge (a - \frac{\epsilon}{2}) - (-a + \frac{\epsilon}{2}) = 2a - \epsilon$. Since the diameter is $\ge 2a-\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0$ it follows that the diameter is $\ge 2a$.

Answer (score 1):

For any $x,y \in A$ we have $|x-y| < 2a$. [If you to prove this claim more rigorously: Suppose without loss of generality that $x \le y$. Then $-a < x \le y < a$ so $y-x < a - (-a) = 2a$.] This shows $\text{diameter}(A) \le 2a$.

To show $\text{diameter}(A) = 2a$, we need to show $\sup_{x,y \in A} |x-y| = 2a$.
For any fixed $\epsilon > 0$, can you find $x,y \in A$ such that $|x-y| \ge 2a - \epsilon$?

Comment: Do we get $\text{diameter}(A) \le 2a$ since $\text{diameter}(A)-\epsilon <|y-x|<2a$ and that implies that $\text{diameter}(A) \le |y-x|<2a$?

Comment: @K.M We showed that $2a$ is an upper bound for $|x-y|$ for all $x,y \in A$. Since the diameter is the supremum (a.k.a. "least upper bound") of these $|x-y|$ values, we must have $\text{diameter}(A) \le 2a$.

Answer (score 1):

You could do, but there are far easier ways. For example, simple note that for $x>y\in A$, we have $|x-y| \leq |a-x|+|x-y|+|y-(-a)| = |a-(-a)| = 2a$, so $2a$ is an upper bound for the diameter of $A$, and also that for any $\varepsilon > 0$ with $\delta := \min(\varepsilon,a)$, if we take $x = a - \frac{\delta}{2}$ and $y = \frac{\delta}{2}-a$, we have $x > y \in A$, and $|x-y| = |2a-\delta| \geq 2a - \delta\geq 2a-\varepsilon$, so $2a$ is also a lower bound for the diameter of $A$, hence is equal to the diameter of $A$.

Comment: I was wondering how you got $|a-(-a)|$ from $|a-x| +|x-y|+|y-(-a)|$?

Comment: Because $-a < y < x < a$, all three of the terms inside the absolute value signs are positive, so $|a - x| + |x - y| + |y - (-a)| = a - x +x-y+y-(-a) = a-(-a) = |a-(-a)|$.

Comment: Since $x>y$, I want to make sure that it follows that $|2a-\delta|=2a-\delta$?

Comment: Yes, that's true.